# Dropped laptop, now get "PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable" error

Tags: boot

I dropped my laptop (toshiba satelite) and now I can only boot up with CD (ubuntu 13.04). Otherwise I come to a black page with text. Text laptop:

```
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press key
```

Questions:

1. Is my hardrive completely destroyed now?
2. I was going to format and reinstall but it says I don't have enough space!! Is it possible to format the hardrive some other way, thereby making more room and then reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: That is an issue with the hardware of your laptop, I would recommend going to an specialist. Or ask in Super User,

Answer (score 1):

The hard drive could have disconnected when it dropped to the floor or if the computer was running whilst it fell to the floor you could have damaged the hard disk. If you don´t know how to open the laptop and check if the SATA cable is connected take it to a shop, if it is the hard drive I recommend the new drive you buy is an SSD, you will never have that problem again as it doesnt have mechanical parts(and you will fly loading OS and apps), hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Brask,I will see if I can open it and have a look... I'm sure it must be quite obvious if anything has disconnected!!

Comment: @Desperate0001 please tell me when you know something new, I hope to be online again tomorrow at morning, I really hope your laptops HDD isn´t dead and that its just something as simple as connecting the cable back again.

Comment: Hi, I have solved the problem!!!

When I opened it and looked if anything was lose I saw that the hardrive had detached from where it should be and when I put it back into its place it WORKED!!!

Thank you everyone who has given me help it is very much appreciated!
Thank goodness for the internet and kind helpers.

:-)

Comment: I'm really glad to hear that you have it working again @Desperate0001 thank your for writing back.

Answer (score 0):

1) Boot from the Live CD
2) Insert a USB FlashDrive and when it is recognized copy the contents of your/dev/sda/home directory (assuming your hard drive is /dev/sda) and all subdirectories beneath it to the flashdrive.
3) From a terminal window, run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` (assuming your hard drive is /dev/sda) and from its menu, delete the partitions
4) Reinstall from your LiveCD
5) Once reinstall is complete, then copy your old /home files back onto the hard drive
6) Take ownership with `sudo find /home -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` also from a terminal window

Comment: Hi Thank you ! I just had to format and reinstall my ubuntu two days ago, so haven't anything on my laptop that I need to save. Could I just somehow delete everything that you just told me to save on USB? and then Reinstall? or?

Comment: Then, if nothing is on there, skip step 2

Comment: Hum... I think you just said that I delete partitions,  think that is what I can do... so I will go and delete and hope all goes well, MANY THANKS!!!

Comment: It tells me that it can't find the directory I wrote what you told me. How do I find out where it is?

Comment: Could I try - sudo fdisk only?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to use GParted?

Comment: @Wilf, is GParted on the 13.04 LiveDVD disk?

Comment: It is the 13.10 one -  you can sort of install some things on Live disks anyway

Comment: fdisk -l will show you what the drive devices are. Could you post what you see there into your question above with the edit link, please? http://linux.die.net/man/8/fdisk will show you more fdisk options.

Answer (score -1):

try:

**sudo fdisk /dev/sda**

it should display something like this:

/dev/sda1   *        2048   201328639   100663296   83  Linux

/dev/sda2       201330686   209713151     4191233    5  Extended

/dev/sda5       201330688   209713151     4191232   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Command (m for help):

try the 'd'.  It will ask for the partition number.  In my case 1,2,5 will work.  If you have problems with fdisk /dev/sda try fdisk -l to see all disk

Comment: It gives me this

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
fdisk: unable to open /dev/sda: No such file or directory

Comment: could dropping the laptop have anything to do with it not finding the file/directory?

Comment: What do you get with 'fdisk -l'

Comment: Problem solved see above. Thanks for all help. :-)